Как в приложении определить, что Android работает в режиме отладки
Многие банковские приложения, когда телефон подключен через USB к компьютеру и идёт трансляция экрана не отображают часть конфиденциальной информации. Например, при входе в приложение нельзя ввести отпечаток пальца. Экран просто тёмный. Пин ввести даёт. После входа в приложение тоже, платежи могут быть недоступны или данные карты. Экран становится тёмным. Вопрос - как это реализуется и как это можно обойти с уже созданными приложениями.
Экран телефона разбил, подключил через scrcpy к компьютеру. Но не могу нормально работать с частью приложений.

Это на уровне системы сделано. Не получится у вас ничего скорее всего. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display#FLAG_SECURE
